# After upgrading to Monterey nfsd not working well

Tags: macos, monterey, virtualbox, nfs

I set up an NFS server on the MacBook Pro to export certain directories in order to share with Ubuntu client running on VirtualBox.  In `/etc/exports`, on the Mac, I have:

```
/Users/xxx/VMShares/Xubuntu -network 192.168.56.0 -mask 255.255.255.0
```

In `/etc/fstab` on Ubuntu I have:

```
192.168.56.1:/Users/xxx/Xubuntu /home/xxx/Mac/ nfs   vers=3  0 0
```

So the share goes on the "host only" network of VirtualBox.  It's been working well for long time on or before Catalina.  I recently upgraded to Monterey from Catalina.  The nfs share works only in some period after I started the virtual client.  After sometime (which doesn't seem to be a fixed amount of time), the shared directory can not be accessed from Ubuntu.

It appears there are two things I can do to make it re-accessible.  One is to toggle the "host only" network connection on the client.  The other is to do `sudo nfsd restart` on the MacBook Pro.  Either way makes the nfs share work, but again only for sometime.

I googled but didn't find related issues.  Any idea what might be wrong?

---

PS: Did a complete uninstall and restall of VirtualBox.  No help?!
On MacOS 12.5.1 and VirtualBox 6.1.36

PS 1: In the end, I installed Ubuntu on a separate partition on the disk, so to dual boot.  Ubuntu boots up so much faster than MacOS, BTW.

PS 2: Completely removed MacOS on the MacBook Pro and only boot to Xubutu 22.04

Comment: Should some of this narrative be placed as an answer or do you still wish to run with macOS on the hardware?

Comment: I don't want to run MacOS anymore on the hardware.  If someone post a solution to this, hope it will help others.